# Cannot get UISearchBar code working

Tags: json, ios6, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

xcode newbie trying to get UISearchBar functionality working.

I am using storyboards and my tableview controller shows a list of events (title, location & start date)in the cells from the array json. When the table firsts loads all of my results are displayed ok. When I click put some text into the search bar (text that exists in the title) nothing is shown in the view controller (I.e. it filters all of the events out). Hopefully this makes a bit more sense.

My header file is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kGETUrl @"http://www.max-momentus.com/fetchevents.php5"

@interface MMAllEventsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *json;
    NSMutableArray *jsonFiltered;
    BOOL isFiltered;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *eventSearchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *eventTableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *categorySelected;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *displayDate;

@end
```

My implementation file is

```
#import "MMAllEventsViewController.h"
#import "MMEventDetailViewController.h"
#import "MMCategoryViewController.h"
#import "MMEventCell.h"

@interface MMAllEventsViewController ()

@end

@implementation MMAllEventsViewController

@synthesize categorySelected, displayDate;

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EventDetailSegue"]) {

        // Segue code
    }
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) getData:(NSData *) data {

    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void) start {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [self getData:data];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.eventSearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.eventTableView.delegate = self;
    self.eventTableView.dataSource = self;

    [self start];

}

-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else {
        isFiltered = YES;
        for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *temp = (NSMutableDictionary*) [json objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [temp valueForKey:@"Title"]];
            NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [jsonFiltered addObject:name];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    [self.eventTableView reloadData];

}

-(void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.eventTableView resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (isFiltered) {
        return [jsonFiltered count];
    }
    return [json count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    MMEventCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MMEventCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (!isFiltered) {
        NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.eventTitleLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.locationLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Location"];

        NSString *startDate = [info objectForKey:@"StartDate"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *sdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yy"];
        NSString *convertedStartDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sdate];

        NSString *endDate = [info objectForKey:@"EndDate"];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *edate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yy"];
        NSString *convertedEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:edate];

        if([sdate isEqualToDate:edate]) {
            displayDate = convertedStartDate;
        } else {
            displayDate = [convertedStartDate stringByAppendingString:@" to "];
            displayDate = [displayDate stringByAppendingString:convertedEndDate];
        }

        cell.datesLabel.text = displayDate;
    }
    else {
        NSDictionary *info = [jsonFiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.eventTitleLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.locationLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Location"];

        NSString *startDate = [info objectForKey:@"StartDate"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *sdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yy"];
        NSString *convertedStartDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sdate];

        NSString *endDate = [info objectForKey:@"EndDate"];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSDate *edate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yy"];
        NSString *convertedEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:edate];

        if([sdate isEqualToDate:edate]) {
            displayDate = convertedStartDate;
        } else {
            displayDate = [convertedStartDate stringByAppendingString:@" to "];
            displayDate = [displayDate stringByAppendingString:convertedEndDate];
        }

        cell.datesLabel.text = displayDate;
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: please be a little more specific with the issue you are facing

Comment: You haven't actually asked us anything. What is your question?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the ambiguity, i will try and be a bit clearer. my tableview controller shows a list of events (title, location & start date)in the cells from the array json. When the table firsts loads all of my results are displayed ok. When I click put some text into the search bar (text that exists in the title) nothing is shown in the view controller (I.e. it filters all of the events out). Hopefully this makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have the delegates:  in your view controllers .h file? Also, make sure you've selected the "UISearchBar and UISearchDisplay Controller" as your search bar object from the storyboard (assuming you're using storyboards). Make sure you've linked your SearchBar to have your view controller be its delegate, and it's connected to an IBOutlet object in your code (again, assuming your using storyboards:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

Finally, make that you have declared a UISearchDisplayController variable, linked it to your *UITableView* and then make sure when loading the results from a search, to check in your

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

if:

```
 if(tableView == searchDisplay):
 {
      ...load results.
 }
 else
 {
      ...load normal view
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm pretty sure I've done everything you've mentioned in your answer, I've added my header and implementation file code. If you wouldn't mind having a look I would really appreciate it. Thank you.